# What is count as moving the value in rust?

Tags: rust, copy

I am trying to implement a function for converting BigInt to vector of u8 in Rust.
`

```
fn BigInt_to_Vector(x: BigInt) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut v : Vec<u8> = vec![];
    let mut n = x.clone();
    let byte : BigInt = BigInt::from(256);

    while(x > BigInt::from(0)) {
        v.push((n%byte).to_u8().unwrap());
        n = n/byte;
    }

    v
}
```

`

I am encountering the following error :
`

```
let byte : BigInt = BigInt::from(256);
   |         ---- move occurs because `byte` has type `BigInt`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

```
v.push((n%byte).to_u8().unwrap());
   |                   ---- value moved here
```

```
n = n/byte;
   |               ^^^^ value used here after move
```

`

I know this error can be directly dealt by deriving the value BigInt::from(256) every time instead of using variable byte (for example, n%byte becomes n%BigInt::from(256)).

But I am unable to understand the reason behind the error even after doing some internet search. And finally, if I want to keep using byte variable, what measures should I take ?

Comment: What library is `BigInt` from?

Comment: BigInt is from num_bigint.

Comment: What I intend to ask is - for types in rust which do not implement the 'copy' trait, how are we supposed to use them as operands ? Do we always have to use their clone explicitly ,i.e. n = n.clone() / BigInt::from(256) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is borrow `n` and `byte` where you don't want them moved:

```rust
fn BigInt_to_Vector(x: BigInt) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut v: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    let mut n = x.clone();
    let byte = BigInt::from(256);
    let zero = BigInt::from(0);

    while x > zero {
        // Borrow `n` and `byte` for the rem op so they aren't moved
        v.push((&n % &byte).to_u8().unwrap());
        // Borrow `byte` for the div op so it isn't moved
        // It's okay if `n` is moved here
        n = n / &byte;
    }

    v
}
```